# React Components from Separate App not integrating into Main App

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node-modules

I'm new to React and I'm doing my best to put together an app, so I've created two main sections and I'm at a point where I would like to combine them, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it.

Here is the **error** I'm getting:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'openSidebar' of undefined`

and it **points to** this component:

```
// Sidebar button and opening of sidebar
// main function created to open sidebar button
import React from 'react';
import { FaBars } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context';

const Home = () => { /*const data can setup data form each button under sidebar */ //<----- ERROR HERE
  const { openSidebar } = useGlobalContext();
  return (
    <main> 
      <button onClick={openSidebar} className='sidebar-toggle'>
        <FaBars />
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I've searched the error in many ways but they all seemed so specific to the app they occurred on.

Thank you for any help you can provide.
**Please let me know if there is more information needed!**

EDIT:
Below is the component that handles the `const` `opendSidebar`

```
// context class need to be added without change,
// setting of close open sidebar
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext(undefined, undefined);

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);

  const openSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(true);
  };
  const closeSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(false);
  };


  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSidebarOpen,
        openSidebar,
        closeSidebar,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Comment: It seems that `useGlobalContext` is returning `undefined`. Without seeing how that is implemented, it's hard to say more.

Comment: I have added the component that handles `useGlobalContext` and `openSidebar`

Comment: `<Home />` needs to be wrapped in a `<AppProvider />` higher up. This would probably be in your root level `<App />` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, it seems that you are missing a `<AppProvider />`. This provides the `context` values to all of the interested children further down. If a context provider is not found the `defaultValue` as provided to `createContext`(in your case undefined) will be used.

Please take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-butterfly-xk679?file=/src/App.js) example. specifically the root `App.js`. You will see a structure similar to

```
<AppProvider>
  <Home />
<AppProvider />
```

Thats really the only thing that's missing.

Answer (score 3):

In React, Context is used to share global properties - thus avoiding the need to pass properties down multiple levels. ContextProvider still needs to be within the component's parent hierarchy so that deeply-nested components will have access to context properties.

In your program, enclose ‘Home’ component inside AppProvider. [ {children} variable inside AppProvider will point to the 'Home' component.]

```
 <AppProvider>
      <Home/>
  </AppProvider>
```

Now, you need to use context properties inside the component. This is done by hook useContext.

```
  const { openSidebar } = useContext(AppContext);
```

The child component (Home) now has access to the nearest AppContext (You can nest multiple AppProviders - the child component will use the nearest Context).

[You do not need useGlobalContext function. The context is already exported in your program. In the “Home” component use the hook 'useContext' and pass AppContext as argument.]

Complete Program is here -

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-integration-wfup1?file=/src/App.js